# Rails 4 rename_column gets MySQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have a MySql5.6 database under Rails 4 on Windows 8.1 (64-bit) and am running migrations to rebuild the database. These migrations work for other developers. That points to something on my system but I don't know what. The error I'm getting is that a rename_table is throwing a MySQL error.

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX `index_bays_on_hub_id` TO `index_w_bays_on_hub_id`' at line 1: ALTER TABLE `w_bays` RENAME INDEX `index_b
ays_on_hub_id` TO `index_w_bays_on_hub_id`C:/Users/Dev/RubymineProjects/ital-freight-manager/db/migrate/20141128123833_rename_bays_to_w_bays.rb:3:in `change'
```

The migration method is

```
def change
  rename_table :bays, :w_bays
end
```

I read this as saying that Rails has generated the ALTER TABLE ... RENAME INDEX .. command which MySQL does not understand. The database configuration specifies this is a MySQL database (and it is a MySQL database) so I'm at a loss to understand why Rails (or maybe it's Ruby) is generating invalid commands. Any help in identifying the problem would be appreciated as I am new to Rails.

*** Just realised this is a rename_table but I was seeing the same with a rename_column which I've done manually. Then it hits this one.

Comment: where is the migration?

Comment: I was adding it as you were asking.

Comment: try to remove indexes manually before rename_table and add it after renaming

Comment: Thanks. I know I can program around this (and had written some generic code for doing so) but I don't want to have to edit migrations to fix a system bug if I can help it. Some further digging suggests that the gem is treating the database as MySQL 5.7 , which DOES support RENAME INDEX. Will just work around it for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need before to delete indexes which referenced to your bays
Rename table
Create new index
Example:

```
def change
  remove_index :bays, name: "index_bays_on_hub_id"
  rename_table :bays, :w_bays
   ... create index
end
```